# weird log in yii2 active record query

Tags: yii2

well I'm working with yii2 and I have , in the database schema , two tables (user and places) and they are related together  via an intermediary table(junction table), i looked what is the best way to get those places that has been created by the user who is currently loged in the application. There are many ways to do it , but I use the next one:

In the User model I made a function called getPlaces():

```
 public function getPlaces(){
    return $this->hasMany(Place::className(),['id'=>'id_place'])
        ->viaTable('OwnerAdmins',['id_user' => 'id']);
}
```

and then I call this function and I pass the result to the view, the weird is that that does not show any places , Iam not getting it no error either , so when I look into the log in the database I can see the next:

> SELECT * FROM ....... WHERE 0=1

well, obviously that wont display any data , but the weird there is 0=1 , i could not find what is going on with that. I have run "grep -lir "0=1" appDirectory" but it seems to be something else, does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

In Yii2, `WHERE 0=1` is the result of an empty IN condition.

This simply means that your user model do not have any `OwnerAdmins` => the query to fetch `places` will have an empty IN condition.